# Как отключить строки с подсказками в VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Как отключить автоматическое выплывание этих строк в VS Code?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Измените в настройках Settings.json

```
"java.debug.settings.enableRunDebugCodeLens": false
```

подробнее [тут](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging)

либо тоже самое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]